# Postgres: Array Search Includes Some Elements

Tags: postgresql

I have a `records` table in my database containing a column called `multi-ids` stored as a `varchar`

```
record_id   multi-ids
        1     [1,2,3]
```

I'm trying to write a query which will return back records which match some of the numbers in the `multi-ids` column

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE multi-ids::jsonb @> '[1,2]'
```

Using that query I was able to get record 1 to come back. However, if I was to search for `[3,4,5]`, nothing comes back.

Is there a query that would work for both cases? If some number matches, then return the record back?

Comment: Use regular arrays instead: `WHERE translate(multi-ids,'[]','{}')::int[] && array[3,4,5]`

Comment: that's a great advice - why not putting as an answer?

Comment: @VaoTsun Because the actual answer should be "Organize your data according to [Normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)" :o)

Comment: yes - this is even better advice! But OP's workaround for existing structure has logical error and you have a solution for it - other people will find it learn